# How to ignore URL inheritence in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, single-page-application, router

I have below route setup like this

This is in the app.routing.ts

```
{
    path: "users",
    loadChildren: () =>
        import("./users/project.module").then(
            (s) => s.UserModule
        ),
},
```

And in the UserModule I have another routing setup like this

```
{
    path: "manage",
    component: ManageUserComponent,
},
```

So I can access the manage route using `users/manage` but is there anyway for me to use only `manage` route ?

I have tried with `../` but no success

```
{
   path: "../manage",
   component: ManageUserComponent,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's possible as you want it (since your app module doesn't know anything about your user module, because it's lazy loading it), however you could add in your app module routing another route redirecting to it:

```js
{
    path: "users",
    loadChildren: () =>
        import("./users/project.module").then(
            (s) => s.UserModule
        ),
},
{
  path: "manage", redirectTo: "users/manage", pathMatch: "full"
}
```

You still have `users/manage` though, but it could be accessed either way

I don't think you can specify an absolute (or a parent) route on `path` (although I admittedly haven't tried)

Comment: Tried with your solution and it work. But I still wonder if there any other solution I could tried

Comment: @TonyNgo I don't think there is if you want to keep lazy loading (not loading the actual components in your app module), but I'm interested too, let's see if anyone else comes up with something!

Answer (score 1):

You can import a UserRoutingModule inside your UserModule, like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: `manage`, component: ManageUserComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class UserRoutingModule { }
```

Then you have only to import your UserModule inside your main module (AppModule).
Angular will use also that child routing module.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all

Comment: Yes, it is. It loses lazy loading but, as you said, there is no other way to get what it says and in this way the route will be "manage" and no longer "user/manage". He will then choose the method he prefers. These are the possibilities.